# How to run the request based on previous request response data

Tags: jmeter

I have test plan with following request in sequence with 2 loops.

1. ApiHttp request
2. Mqtt request

I need to run 1st loop & verify API reaponse is true or false:

If it's true, run Mqtt request , else start the 2nd loop and same verify the API response, if it's true run Mqtt else stop.

In above scenarios, I put beanshell to read the API response:

```
   vars.put("response", new String(data));
```

But don't know how to verify of its true or false  & execute the Mqtt. Any help pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage/) as the very first test element under the Thread Group and use the [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) as the condition:

   ```
   ${__groovy(vars.getIteration() <= 2,)}
   ```
2. Put `ApiHttp request` as a child of the If Controller
3. Add another If Controller after the `ApiHttp request` and use the following __groovy() function as the condition:

   ```
   ${__groovy(ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseDataAsString().contains('true'))}
   ```
4. Add `Mqtt request` as a child of the If Controller
5. Add [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler after the `Mqtt request` and configure it like:

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

First switch from Beanshell to JSR223 Test elements and use Groovy.

Use [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) and just put in it:

> ${response}

To stop the test based on iteration number, be aware that a Loop Controller exposes iteration as a variable based on name of variable, for example if your LoopController is named LC, then you can access iteration as:

> vars["__jm__LC__idx"].toInteger()

And to stop a test from Groovy using JSR223 Assertion you can throw:

> throw new  org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterStopTestException();

See:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jorphan/util/JMeterStopTestException.html